# Why does .data() work on a set collection of elements, but not on a single element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of divs on my webpage, all with the data attribute `data-duration`.

When I run the `.data("duration")` on all my divs, I get the `data-duration` of the first div. When I run it on a single element I get an error.

Here is an example:

```
$(".reservation").data("duration")
>> 170
$(".reservation")[0].data("duration")
>> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

This code fails as well:

```
$(".reservation").each(function(index, elem) {
  return console.log(elem.data("duration"));
});
```

I get a similar error with `.attr("data-duration")` on single elements.

Why can't I get the data attribute of a single element?

Comment: It fails because `.data()` is a jQuery function, and `[0]` returns a HTMLElement. Use `.first()` to get the equivalent jQuery elt. (Same for `.each` - use `$(elem)` or `$(this)` to get the jQuery elt)

Comment: or do $($(".reservation")[0]).data("duration")

Comment: Thanks! If you make this into an answer I will be able to mark it as correct.

Comment: FYI, the js `hybrid` equivalent is `$(".reservation")[0].dataset.duration` on all modern browsers supporting dataset object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the raw DOM element from the jQuery collection with [].

Use `.eq(0)` or `first()` to get the first "jQuery" element:

```
$(".reservation").eq(0).data("duration")
```

or

```
$(".reservation").first().data("duration")
```

Your second piece of code fails as you are again referencing the DOM element (passed as elem) instead of the jQuery one:

Try using `this` instead: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/rd55sdbd/2/

```
$(".reservation").each(function() {
  console.log($(this).data("duration"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`elem` of each method is pure HTML element and not jQuery object hence your code was not working. Please try below code.

**HTML code**

```
<div class="reservation" data-duration="10"></div>
<div class="reservation" data-duration="20"></div>
<div class="reservation" data-duration="30"></div>
<div class="reservation" data-duration="40"></div>
<div class="reservation" data-duration="50"></div>
```

**JavaScript code:**

```
$('.reservation').each(function(index,elem){
    alert($(elem).data('duration'));
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rtkdvkv9/1/)